# Android Studio Bluetooth Service and Local Broadcast

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I am working on an Android project using Bluetooth. The project is communicating with an Arduino, but I'm having trouble accessing values from within Android. I think problem is on the local broadcast side.

Here's the service class and the fragment code:

```
Handler bluetoothIn;

    final int handlerState = 0;                         //used to identify handler message
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private Intent intent;
    private LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager;

    // SPP UUID service - this should work for most devices
    private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // String for MAC address
    private static String address;

    public final static String DATE_TIME_ACTION = "info.devexchanges.dateservice";




    private final Handler handler=new Handler();

    public final static String AKIM="Akim";
    public final static String GERILIM="Gerilim";
    public final static String  DIRENC="Direnc";
    public final static String  SICAKLIK="Sicaklik";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == handlerState) {                                     //if message is what we want
                    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                                                // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
                    recDataString.append(readMessage);                                      //keep appending to string until ~
                    int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");                    // determine the end-of-line

                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // make sure there data before ~
                        String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string


                        if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#')                             //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
                        {


                            String []ar=dataInPrint.split("[+]");


                            String sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1, 5);             //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5
                            String sensor1 = recDataString.substring(6, 10);            //same again...
                            String sensor2 = recDataString.substring(11, 16);
                            String sensor3 = recDataString.substring(17, 21);

                            //sensorView0.setText(" Ölçülen Voltaj = " +ar[1] + " V");  //update the textviews with sensor values
                            //sensorView1.setText(" Ölçülen Akım = " + ar[2] + " A");
                            //sensorView2.setText(" Ölçülen Sıcaklık = " + ar[3] + " C");
                            //sensorView3.setText(" Ölçülen Direnç = " + ar[4] + " Ohm");
                            Log.e("Veri",ar[3]);

                            intent=new Intent(DATE_TIME_ACTION);
                            intent.putExtra(AKIM,ar[2]);
                            intent.putExtra(GERILIM,ar[1]);
                            intent.putExtra(DIRENC,ar[4]);
                            intent.putExtra(SICAKLIK,ar[3]);
                            broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);




                        }
                        recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    //clear all string data
                        // strIncom =" ";
                        dataInPrint = " ";
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
        checkBTState();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.e("Deneme","deneme");


        //Get the MAC address from the DeviceListActivty via EXTRA
        //address = intent.getStringExtra(address);

        //address=(String) intent.getExtras().get("device_address");
        address=intent.getStringExtra("device_address");
        Log.e("Doğru Adres",address);

        //create device and set the MAC address
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
        try
        {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try
            {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2)
            {
                //insert code to deal with this
            }
        }
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        //I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check device is connected
        //If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and finish() will be called
        mConnectedThread.write("x");

        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second
        return START_STICKY;

    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getDateTimes();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 1 seconds
        }
    };

    public void getDateTimes() {

        bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == handlerState) {                                     //if message is what we want
                    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                                                // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
                    recDataString.append(readMessage);                                      //keep appending to string until ~
                    int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");                    // determine the end-of-line

                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // make sure there data before ~
                        String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string


                        if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#')                             //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
                        {


                            String [] ar=dataInPrint.split("[+]");


                            String sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1, 5);             //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5
                            String sensor1 = recDataString.substring(6, 10);            //same again...
                            String sensor2 = recDataString.substring(11, 16);
                            String sensor3 = recDataString.substring(17, 21);

                            //sensorView0.setText(" Ölçülen Voltaj = " +ar[1] + " V");  //update the textviews with sensor values
                            //sensorView1.setText(" Ölçülen Akım = " + ar[2] + " A");
                            //sensorView2.setText(" Ölçülen Sıcaklık = " + ar[3] + " C");
                            //sensorView3.setText(" Ölçülen Direnç = " + ar[4] + " Ohm");
                            Log.e("Veri",ar[3]);

                            intent=new Intent(DATE_TIME_ACTION);
                            intent.putExtra(AKIM,ar[2]);
                            intent.putExtra(GERILIM,ar[1]);
                            intent.putExtra(DIRENC,ar[4]);
                            intent.putExtra(SICAKLIK,ar[3]);
                            Log.e("Service Yollama",address);
                            broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);




                        }
                        recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    //clear all string data
                        // strIncom =" ";
                        dataInPrint = " ";
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
        checkBTState();


    }




    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
        //creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
    }

    private void checkBTState() {

        if(btAdapter==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            } else {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            }
        }
    }


    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        //creation of the connect thread
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                //Create I/O streams for connection
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }


        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            // Keep looping to listen for received messages
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //write method
        public void write(String input) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);                //write bytes over BT connection via outstream
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //if you cannot write, close the application
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        broadcastReceiver=new BroadCastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                super.onReceive(context, intent);
                degeral(intent);
            }
        };
        intent=new Intent(getActivity(),BluetoothDataService.class);

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver((broadcastReceiver),new IntentFilter(BluetoothDataService.DATE_TIME_ACTION));// Buraya Yazılacak
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);// Buraya Yazılacak
    }

    private void degeral(Intent intent)
    {
        ger.setText(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDataService.DATE_TIME_ACTION));
        Log.e("Sicaklik",intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDataService.DATE_TIME_ACTION));
    }
```

Comment: why do you need to `sendBroadcast`? why not to use [local bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder) pattern (or at least use [Messenger](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger) class?)

Comment: I checked your advice but i didn't understand it . İm using send broadcast because i need send bluetooth data to multiple fragments. Can i solve without send broadcast?

Comment: you are calling `bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(...)` in a working thread and posting it to a `Handler`, instead you can obtain a new `Message` and use it in `Messenger#send(Message message)`

Comment: Alright i will try it thx

Comment: Minor edits for legibility of the question.